# Add multiple objects of same model at the same time in the django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model to upload pictures:

```
class Snap(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

In the admin it contains all the `Snap`'s field (i.e. one field to upload an image ,its caption and the pubdate) which is as expected. How do I add multiple record of `Snap`'s in one go. I hope I was clear, if not please ask. Your help and guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

admin.py:

```
class SnapAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Snap

admin.site.register(Snap, SnapAdmin)
```

Comment: Like having an inline that can allow you to add multiple items?  Maybe there is a way to use that?

Comment: @PhoebeB Yes. To add multiple `Snap`s in one place.

Comment: @Robin That can be done by `admin.StackedInline` or `admin.TabularInline` if `Snap` has a `ForeignKey` to another model.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create multiple objects in django admin at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563352/create-multiple-objects-in-django-admin-at-once)