# Create multiple objects in django admin at once

Tags: django, django-admin

For example, I have a Post model:

```
Class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    # other fields
```

I wonder is there a way to create multiple posts at once in admin. In other words, I need a formset instead of single form on post creation page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, the best way to do exactly what you want is extend the [`ModelAdmin class`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L476), because it has no formsets on it, except for those used on InlineFormsets.

After that you could customize the admin [change_form template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html#L56), to include your formsets

The quick-and-dirty way to do it using admin is wrap your Post model as an inline formset of another modeladmin and add the `extra` option to it.

Comment: 1) I want to explicitly mark those models, that need a formset. I guess, your solution is non-selective and will make all models look the same.
2) Inline is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, you still need to create a new ModelAdmin class with a formset property and a formset flag, marking if you want the specific admin form to use formsets and the number of extra_forms. @chem1st

Answer (score 7):

I've heard recently about a django app that exactly does this job. It's called [django-bulk-admin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-bulk-admin) and enables bulk add/update in the admin.

Comment: They are doing exactly what I told, they have created BulkModelAdmin that extends ModelAdmin Class and add formsets. Then they've created templates for change_form.

Comment: @FernandoFreitasAlves : you're right ! I didn't investigate, in fact I just found the package on Reddit and thought the OP would be interested by a third-party answer instead of writing it from scratch.

Comment: @EliotBerriot But fields cannot be excluded with this! And what about model_save method overriding? Is that possible?

Comment: @edam to be honest, I never used the package so I don't really know. You'll have to look in the package code itself or open an issue to ask your question :)

Comment: The module does not support django 3+, the last commit was in 2015.